Firebase messaging from bubble
I've got a simple HTML element in Bubble.io that I'm trying to run javascript from.
Here's the error:
Uncaught Error: Service messaging is not available
    at Provider.getImmediate (provider.ts:130:15)
    at getMessagingInWindow (api.ts:64:61)
    at about:blank:35:19

and here's the pseudocode:
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "firebase/app": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js",
        "firebase/messaging": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-messaging.js"
    }
}
</script>
  <script type="module">
   import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
   import { getMessaging } from 'firebase/messaging';
   const firebaseConfig = {
   //...my config
   };

   // Initialize Firebase
   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const messaging = getMessaging(app); // ERROR HERE
   console.log(messaging)
</script>



Has anyone solved this? How can I run the push notifications script from a bubble page?

First, always make the versions match on your firebase imports. It's also a good idea to make sure you're on the latest version.

@DougStevenson good eye. The error went away. If you submit as an answer I'll accept.

The versions of your Firebase SDK imports are mismatched.  Make sure they are always the same version.  It's also a good idea to make sure you're on the latest.
